# Extract particular data from multiple files in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Extract a particular column value from multiple files

ls -ltr

```
-rwxr-xr-x   4 dc staff   131 Feb 27 21:15 test.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   4 dc staff   134 Feb 25 21:15 test1.txt
```

test.txt and test1.txt (similar structure) contains a table structure like

cat test.txt

```
RECORD #1 DETAILS

    sl no.  regno  name  age
     1       20    ABC   10
```

cat test1.txt

```
RECORD #2 DETAILS

      sl no.  regno  name  age
       1       21    DEF   11
```

I want to extract the 2nd column value from all .txt files and store it into some other files.

Ouput.txt should be

```
test.txt 20
test1.txt 21
```

Comment: I have used awk command to print the 2nd column. But few extra texts were printed along with the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are looking for, but if you just want to print the second column of the 4th line (and that is the ambiguity, as it's not clear if you always want the data from line 4, or the data from 3 lines after ^RECORD, or data from the line after each occurrence of "sl no.", etc), you could do:

```
$ awk 'FNR == 4 { print FILENAME, $2 }' test.txt test1.txt
```

or, if you are using an awk that does not support FILENAME (at the moment, I'm not sure if that is standard or a gnu extension) and you are not using csh or one of its cousins, you could do:

```
$ for n in test.txt test1.txt; do printf '$s ' $n; awk 'NR==4{ print $2}' $n; done
```

Comment: Both FILENAME and FNR are specified for awk in the open group standard.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print FILENAME, $2}' *txt > Output.txt
```

Might work for you. But if you want to make sure, that only parts after the header should be printed, you can do it like:

```
awk 'fname != FILENAME {p=0 ; fname=FILENAME} } 
     /sl no.  regno  name  age/ {p++; next}
     p>0 {print FILENAME, $2}' *txt > Output.txt
```

Comment: I have updated the input files. I used awk but couldnot get the 2nd column. It generated few other text along with the required answer. I need only the number (as in output.txt)

Comment: You can use the standard variable FNR for record number in the current file instead of manipulating p.

Comment: Yes but what if there are more header like lines, varying from file to file?